# SharePoint GetListItems Across Domain

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, cross-domain, jsonp

I basically need to perform a GetListItems from a SharePoint list on a different server. I have tried different codes but they all error out. Can someone look at what I have and see if it's wrong or if it's just not possible? I get the Error alert then an xData.ResponseText alert as 'undefined'. Nothing after that. The server where I'm running the code is server3.intranet.com. Thank you.

```
var soapEnv =
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
        <soapenv:Body> \
             <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                <listName>Shared Documents</listName> \
                <viewFields> \
                    <ViewFields> \
                        <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                   </ViewFields> \
                </viewFields> \
            </GetListItems> \
        </soapenv:Body> \
    </soapenv:Envelope>";

function Result(xData, status) {
    alert(xData.responseText);
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
        var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
        alert(title);
    });
}

    $.ajax({
    url: "http://teams02.intranet.com/sites/MySite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSONP",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: soapEnv,
    complete: Result,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
 error:function(){
     alert("Error");
 }
```

So is there anything that needs to be changed in this code? And is the url that I'm using correct? I'm not sure exactly what I should be pointing this at--if it's the list itself or some sort of virtual path.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OOTB Lists.asmx doesn't support JSONP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
$(function(){
    var soapEnv = 
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
        <soapenv:Body> \
            <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                <listName>Shared Documents</listName> \
                <viewFields> \
                    <ViewFields> \
                        <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                    </ViewFields> \
                </viewFields> \
            </GetListItems> \
        </soapenv:Body> \
     </soapenv:Envelope>";
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://servername/mysite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        complete: function(xData, status){
            $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function(){
                var title = $(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef").split("#")[1];
                alert(title);
            })
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for your response! This certainly helped. I tried it and it threw a No Transport error. I added `jQuery.support.cors = true;` before your code and it worked (in IE). In FF it doesn't return anything. When I do an alert(xData.responseXML) it is empty whereas in IE it shows the XML payload. Any ideas??

Comment: Update: I suspect is has to do with Active Directory. IE is probably passing my credentials to the other server while FF is not. I don't know if there's a way to do that manually in the JavaScript for FF users.

Comment: If you download the jQuery library and then upload it to your SharePoint server then reference the local copy, it will work.

Comment: I tested with chrome and saw the empty payload you described.  With chrome if I switch it to xData.responseText, it works.  With FF it works with xData.responseXML (after referencing a local jQuery copy).

Comment: I don't think this will work across domains... Did you actually get it to work that way?

Comment: responseText fixed made mine work in chrome (and IE), but we are in sharepoint going from one site collection to another on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

You're risking to face a cross site scripting. In order to accomplish your goal I'd advice you to create a service on the same server your javascript comes from and implement all the logic to retrieve data from the other server in this local service (i.e. using Linq2SharePoint or SOAP API). This would be the most reliable way from the point of view of the security and cross-browser implementation.