# Cross-Subdomain Sharepoint List Access

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, cross-domain

I am trying to access list data from **neighbor.domain.com** using Javascript on **home.domain.com**.  Both are Sharepoint 2007.

I am using the code from [this question's top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469980/sharepoint-getlistitems-across-domain).

```
$(function(){
    var soapEnv = 
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
        <soapenv:Body> \
            <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                <listName>Documents</listName> \
                <viewFields> \
                    <ViewFields> \
                        <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                    </ViewFields> \
                </viewFields> \
            </GetListItems> \
        </soapenv:Body> \
     </soapenv:Envelope>";
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://neighbor.domain.com/sites/site1/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        complete: function(xData, status){
            $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function(){
                var title = $(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef").split("#")[1];
                alert(title);
            })
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

It does not work for me.  I get an error: **Access is Denied**.
I have added `jQuery.support.cors = true` but no luck there, either.

Is there something I'm missing?  Is it required to implement something at the other domain(**neighbor.domain.com**)?

I do not have administrative access to the server machines (only developer access to Sharepoint).  I only have read access to **neighbor.domain.com**.

**UPDATE (July 10, 2013)**: I have more than read access to **neighbor.domain.com**.  My solution involved adding a file on the other subdomain which would retrieve list data based on URL parameters passed to it.

Comment: Are you perhaps getting a double hop issue with NT authentication?

Comment: Is there some way I can test that?  I had not heard of the double hop issue until today.  Based off of [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2008/08/22/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue.aspx): I know anonymous access is disabled, not sure about impersonation.

Comment: You can test by hard coding the credentials for the ajax call.

Comment: Figured out my issue, somewhat; I needed to [enable accessing data sources across domains](http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests) -- for IE exclusively.  Unfortunately, that requires changing IE security settings and not all of the users accessing the site will be able to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My eventual solution involved adding a file that acted as a proxy for retrieving data on **neighbor.domain.com**, using Javascript.

Script on **neighbor.domain.com**:

```js
document.domain = 'domain.com';  // Important, so that both pages are considered
                                 // the same domain.  Allows us to access the
                                 // parent object when this page is loaded in an
                                 // iframe on the same domain.

// Returns value of URL parameter
function getURLParameter(name) { ... }    

// Retrieves URL parameters that tell the proxy what to do
// The Web services operation to call
var operation = getURLParameter("operation");
// The URL path of the site (i.e. /sites/sitename)
var weburl = getURLParameter("weburl");
// The name of the list on the site
var listname = getURLParameter("listname");

// Run the requested web service operation
if (operation === "GetListItems") {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: operation,
    listName: listname,
    webURL: weburl,
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      // parent is a defined object when this page is loaded in an iframe on the
      // same domain.  The parent must have a 'passListItemsData' function
      // defined.
      parent.passListItemsData(xData.responseXML);
    }
  });
}
// Add more operations (and recognized URL params) as needed
else if (...) {...}
```

Calling script on **home.domain.com**:

```js
document.domain = 'domain.com';  // Important, so that both pages are considered
                                 // the same domain.  Allows the proxy page to
                                 // access functions defined on this page.

// Create an iframe that makes a request of the proxy file using URL parameters
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.style.display = "none";
iframe.src = "neighbor.domain.com/path/proxyfile.html?operation=GetListItems&" + 
             "weburl=/sitepath/sitename&listname=name";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);  // Requests proxy page and kicks off the
                                    // process

/**
 * Implements the passListItemsData function for the subdomain proxy.  This
 * handles the results of a GetListItems function on the other subdomain.
 * @param data, results returned by the GetListItems Lists web service function
 */
function passListItemsData(data) {
  // Handle returned XML data from GetListItems web service
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my answer for that question. That is easier :) It is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478130/833337)

Comment: Would that work in a situation where I do not have administrative access to the actual server machine?

Comment: If follow coding best practices - no. But if you can cope with dirty solutions than yes. You might create a sandbox solution with a webpart and place it on the page somewhere in the same domain. then you request that page in js (this page might be the same page you script runs on) with a special request (i.e. a param in query string) and during the handling of the request webpart sees that this is the request of your special type and connects to your other domain and then renders the output. then you parse the outcome of the ajax request and get you results.

Comment: So what you're saying: create a custom web part using, say, C# that would request info from the other domain based on URL query string parameters?

Comment: hm. are the 2 domains located in the same SharePoint Farm?

Comment: I can't say with 100% accuracy, but I'm fairly certain that they are not.

Comment: Then you gotta request admin access for this solution to work because SB solutions have limitations on calling external services.